# Azure AD Go SDK daemon application list users returns "Access Token missing or malformed"

Tags: azure, go, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am attempting to retrieve user details via the graph API Go SDK. I have a [daemon application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-app-types#daemons-and-server-side-apps) which has been setup with adequate permissions that I have validated via `curl` as shown below:

**Get token**

```
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
  --data 'client_id={client_id}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials' \

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

**Request**

```
curl -X GET \
 -H "Authorization: Bearer XYZ...." \
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
```

I successfully get a list of users.

---

However, when I attempt this via the Go SDK it fails.

I have set the required environment variables for authentication as per https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go#more-authentication-details:

```
- `AZURE_TENANT_ID`: Specifies the Tenant to which to authenticate.
- `AZURE_CLIENT_ID`: Specifies the app client ID to use.
- `AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET`: Specifies the app secret to use
```

**Code**

```
func main() {

    authorizer, err := auth.NewAuthorizerFromEnvironment()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    client := graphrbac.NewUsersClient(os.Getenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID"))
    client.Authorizer = authorizer

    if _, err := client.List(context.Background(), "", ""); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("list users", err)
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
list users graphrbac.UsersClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=401 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_MissingOrMalformed","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Access Token missing or malformed."}}}]
```

The documentation [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go#authentication) to me suggests that the authentication and token is handled by the `auth` package.

**Update 1**

I ran it debug mode by setting `AZURE_GO_SDK_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG` and found that the `GET` request URL is different to what I used in my `curl` command:

```
(2020-06-16T15:31:49.3790420+10:00) INFO: REQUEST: GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/users?api-version=1.6
User-Agent: Go/go1.13.11 (amd64-darwin) go-autorest/v14.1.1 Azure-SDK-For-Go/v43.2.0 graphrbac/1.6
Authorization: **REDACTED**
(2020-06-16T15:31:50.5191120+10:00) INFO: RESPONSE: 401 https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/users?api-version=1.6
```

If I use that URL in my `curl` command I get:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_ExpiredToken","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Your access token has expired. Please renew it before submitting the request."}}}%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the sdk uses azure ad graph api but not microsoft graph api in the backend.

Azure AD graph api shows like: `https://graph.windows.net/{tenant_id}/users?api-version=1.6`

Microsoft graph api shows like: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users`

So you need to add the azure ad graph permissions for the application registered in your azure ad, but not add the microsoft graph permissions. Please add the permission by following the steps below:

**1.** Go to your application in your azure ad and click "API permissions" --> "Add a permission" --> "Azure Active Directory Graph".
[image]

**2.** Add the "Directory" permission.
[image]

**3.** Don't forget grant admin consent for it.

Comment: Thanks for giving all those details! I'll give it a shot and confirm.

Comment: This is correct as per https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/7352

Answer (score 0):

It seems that ADAL is already deprecated although MSAL is not yet ready (in an SDK).

**Azure Console**:
[image]

**[microsoft-authentication-library-for-go](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-go)**:
[image]

Which means that [@hury-shen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11099213/hury-shen) answer is still valid.