# How to check a user's group in Azure using go lang?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have the following code which primarily looks for the groups a user can be part of:

```
package main



 import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "log"
    
        "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac"
        //"github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest"
        "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"
    )
    const (
    clientID       = 
    clientSecret   = 
    tenantID       = 
    userPrincipalName = username@myorg.com
)
func main() {
    // Create an Azure authentication authorizer
    authorizer, err := auth.NewClientCredentialsConfig(clientID, clientSecret, tenantID).Authorizer()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create Azure authorizer: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a new Graph Rbac Management client
    graphClient := graphrbac.NewGroupsClient(tenantID)
    graphClient.Authorizer = authorizer
    fmt.Println("----")
    // Retrieve the groups that the user is a member of
    groups, err := graphClient.List(context.TODO(), fmt.Sprintf("members/userPrincipalName eq '%s'", userPrincipalName))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to retrieve group memberships: %v", err)
    }

    // Print the group names
    for _, group := range groups.Values() {
        fmt.Println(*group.DisplayName)
    }
}
```

When I run this I get :

```
2023/06/22 23:40:24 Failed to retrieve group memberships: graphrbac.GroupsClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=401 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authentication_MissingOrMalformed","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Access Token missing or malformed."}}}]
```

I have checked that I have necessary permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that, your code uses **Azure AD Graph API** in the backend that is currently deprecated.
>
> There is SDK for MS Graph named `msgraph-sdk-go` that uses **Microsoft Graph API** but it is still in non-production preview where it updates often.

I have one user named **`Sri`** which is a member of below Azure AD groups:

[image]

When I ran same go lang code as you in my environment to get these group names, I got **same error** as below:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/graphrbac/1.6/graphrbac"
    //"github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest"
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"
)

const (
    clientID          = "appID"
    clientSecret      = "secret"
    tenantID          = "tenantID"
    userPrincipalName = "user1@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
)

func main() {
    // Create an Azure authentication authorizer
    authorizer, err := auth.NewClientCredentialsConfig(clientID, clientSecret, tenantID).Authorizer()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create Azure authorizer: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a new Graph Rbac Management client
    graphClient := graphrbac.NewGroupsClient(tenantID)
    graphClient.Authorizer = authorizer
    fmt.Println("----")
    // Retrieve the groups that the user is a member of
    groups, err := graphClient.List(context.TODO(), fmt.Sprintf("members/userPrincipalName eq '%s'", userPrincipalName))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to retrieve group memberships: %v", err)
    }

    // Print the group names
    for _, group := range groups.Values() {
        fmt.Println(*group.DisplayName)
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of below **PowerShell script** to get the **display names** of groups where user is a member of like this:

```
Connect-AzureAD

$userPrincipalName = "sri@xxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
$user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName eq '$userPrincipalName'"
$groups = Get-AzureADUserMembership -ObjectId $user.ObjectId | Where-Object { $_.ObjectType -eq "Group" }

foreach ($group in $groups) {
    Write-Host $group.DisplayName
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**References:**

[Azure AD Go SDK daemon application list users returns "Access Token missing or malformed" - Stack Overflow by **Hury Shen**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400615/azure-ad-go-sdk-daemon-application-list-users-returns-access-token-missing-or-m)

[Azure Active Directory API Deprecated ·  Azure/azure-sdk-for-go (github.com) by **Markus Blaschke**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/7352#issuecomment-1203317533)